# Is there a list of functions that I can use inside kernel?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to develop a new system call and add it to the kernel, but since the c file that contains the syscall method implementation can only use functions which reside inside the kernel address space I'm pretty sure I can't use methods like popen, stat, etc.. 
I made a bit of research on the Internet but I couldn't find anything that would give me the functions that I can use inside the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the biggest difference (among many big differences) that you will need to get your head around is this: the kernel is not linked against `libc`. So, look at everything provided by `libc`. you don't get any of that...

...well, sort of. Some of the functionality that `libc` provides is actually implemented inside the kernel itself. You need to include the kernel versions of those headers:

```
#include <linux/[header file].h>
```

To get an idea of what is available inside the kernel, you'll need to look at the functions defined in the header files of the kernel source tree.

A few other points to keep in mind:

- Linux kernel is programmed using GNU C, not strict ANSI C, which makes sense: as some folks would be quick to point out, Linux is just the kernel, GNU is everything else; that includes the GCC compiler.
- No easy floating point math. Normally the kernel facilitates the use of floating point instructions, but the mechanism it uses to that cannot be easily used on the kernel itself. See [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/lib/math) for more.

A good book on the subject is [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) (I am in no way affiliated; it's just a good book).